# Laravel cannot acces shared storage

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, storage

I have a problem with accessing shared network storage from my laravel app. It is mounted into /mnt/nfs/ folder inside my ubuntu server. I can access that folder/storage directly via terminal but when I try to use this folder as root folder for laravel storage. I receive this error: "impossible to create the root directory "/mnt/nfs/app". The folder app is already located inside that shared storage.

Is there any settings in laravel config to enable shared storage? Also I've already tried to change permissions for the folder to 774 and ownership to www-data, but without any success.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find your storage folder path location then you try

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /your_storage_path/storage/*
```

Comment: Still receiving same error. Set storage to 777.

Answer (score 0):

You need to full permission of folder, 2 way you give permission.

1. `sudo chmod -R 777 /storage_path/storage`
2. go to your project and right click on storage folder then select properties and give all  permissions.

I hope it will be work.

Comment: Still receiving same error. Set storage to 777.